# Search for multiple substrings when looping through a series. (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a more efficient way to do the following? Ideally, by using only one if statement?

Suppose there is a dataframe with an "author" series, a "comedy" series (default = True), and a "horror" series (default = False). I want to search the author series for "stephen king" and "lovecraft" and in those cases change the value of "comedy" from True to False and change the value of "horror" from False to True.

```
for count,text in enumerate(df.loc[0:, "author"]):
    if "stephen king" in str(text):
        df.loc[count, "comedy"] = False
        df.loc[count, "horror"] = True
        continue
    elif "lovecraft" in str(text):
        df.loc[count, "comedy"] = False
        df.loc[count, "horror"] = True
        continue
```

When I try using str.contains(), I get the error "str' object has no attribute 'str'".

Answer (score 1):

Don't enumerate a data frame, index and slice it.

```
ix = df.author.str.contains('stephen king')
df.loc[ix, 'comedy'] = False
df.loc[ix, 'horror'] = True

ix = df.author.str.contains('lovecraft')
df.loc[ix, 'comedy'] = False
df.loc[ix, 'horror'] = True
```

Comment: In the first example, is ix the index of those that do contain stephen king?

Comment: Yes.  Stephen King for the first block, and Lovecraft for the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign these values with df.loc. If string contains 'stephen king' or 'lovecraft', put False in column 'comedy' and True in column 'horror':

```
df.loc[df['author'].str.contains('stephen king|lovecraft'), 
       ['comedy', 'horror']] = [False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the column contains of several values by using

```
df['Author'].str.contains('|'.join(list_of_authors)
```

then assign the values using loc.

Ex;

```
>>> df
          Author  Comedy  Horror
0   stephen king    True   False
1      lovecraft    True   False
2  jonathan ames    True    True
3   stephen king   False    True
4          oprah    True   False
>>> df.loc[df['Author'].str.contains('|'.join(['stephen king','lovecraft']),case=False,na=False),('Comedy','Horror')]=False,True
>>> df
          Author  Comedy  Horror
0   stephen king   False    True
1      lovecraft   False    True
2  jonathan ames    True    True
3   stephen king   False    True
4          oprah    True   False
```